# why does less seem to think my terminal has more lines than it does?

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

Don't know if this is really an OS X question, but:

`less` seems to insist that my terminal (whether I'm using the builtin Terminal or iTerm2) has more lines than are actually displayed, and so the top of whatever I'm `less`ing is always off the screen.

My LINES environment variable matches the number of visible lines in the terminal.

I have a vague recollection that it didn't use to be this way, but has been this way for me for several months, at least.

Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe `less` is suggesting you use `more` :-p.  I can't reproduce this on Lion.  Have you changed your LESS environment variable?

Comment: Does it happen with all files or only with specific ones?

Comment: I have the same problem with 'less'.  'more' works for me, good suggestion.